# Myriad Pro on CS6 Flash is no longer embeding properly

Tags: flash, windows-7, fonts, adobe, embed

If I open an FLA that embeds Myriad Pro for run time sharing, the font comes up blank in the IDE and during run time if I publish it. If the font is not embedded, you see it normally in textFields. This is the only font that does this. I have been using Myriad for a very long time and this is the first time I have encountered the problem.

I'm using Windows 7 / CS6.

The font doesn't appear to fully uninstall when I try to do so. When I uninstall and reboot, then re-install, I am always asked if would I like to copy over the existing Myriad Pro Regular as if it was still installed, but that font is not found in the directory (including if I view the directoy using the command prompt).

If I open the flash file on a computer with CS5 or 5.5 the file opens, runs and publishes correctly.

This issue only started recently even though I have been using my new Windows 7 machine for months.

Thanks for any help you can provide!!!

Comment: I'm not positive but isn't Myriad Pro one of the core fonts of the Adobe CS package? (trying to figure out why it doesn't allow you to uninstall it)

Comment: It is a part of the core fonts. Not sure why that would affect things, but maybe you know something I don't know. It could have been corrupted during an update.

Comment: I'm on a Mac but I remember there was this launcher application that run (in the bg) each time the computer starts up. If it still exists then perhaps it looks for necessary/core files at that time and notifies you when there's a problem. In your case it seems it checks the font and if it can't find it it creates a copy from that embedded in the application into your fonts folder. About embedding, I can't help because I don't have CS6 installed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the last Windows security update [KB2753842](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2753842)
After this, everthing is fine.